# Ceiling function inequality

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-number-theory, functions, inequality

In class, we used the fact that $\lceil{a + b \rceil} \geq \lceil{a}\rceil + \lfloor{b}\rfloor$. However, we weren't given a proof of this statement.

I am interested to see how this works. Can anyone help? Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By definition:
$$b\geq \lfloor b\rfloor$$
Adding $a$ to both sides:
$$a+b \geq a+ \lfloor b\rfloor$$
Taking the ceiling of both sides:
$$\lceil a + b\rceil \geq \lceil a + \lfloor b\rfloor\rceil = \lceil a\rceil + \lfloor b \rfloor$$

This uses that if $n$ is an integer, then 
$$\lceil a + n\rceil = \lceil a \rceil + n$$
And if $x\geq y$ then $$\lceil x \rceil \geq \lceil y\rceil$$

Comment: Oh wow, that turned out to be way easier than I thought. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

By subtracting off integer parts, we can prove this for numbers in $[0,1)$.  Unless both are $0$ the right side is $1$, and then the left is at least $1$.